What do we call a person who never intentionally ignores others and always acknowledge other's actions or gestures and value them?
I am not getting a perfect word for this type of person. First I thought that 'Considerate' will be the right word but then I found that being considerate doesn't mean to acknowledge the other's efforts. So I need a word exclusively for the person having this quality.
Thank you.

Does it have to be a single word?

Welcome! Please edit the question to include an example sentence showing how the word will be used. It's not even stated whether you are looking for an adjective or a noun.

A mensch, "A mensch, in Yiddish, is a person of integrity, morality, dignity, with a sense of what is right and responsible. But mensch is more than just an old Yiddish adage. It is relevant now, across the world, more than ever… “To be a mensch is to be supportive. To be a friend, to be calm in troubled times."

@user862888 Worthy of being an answer.

Personally, I'd say, "a person who never intentionally ignores others and always acknowledge other's actions or gestures and value them".
We often get these questions on this site, "What is a single word in English that means a tall, blue-eyed man wearing a sweater and riding a bicycle on a Thursday?" Often there is no single word to express a complex idea.
In this case I see several suggestions, but in my humble opinion, none SPECIFICALLY mean the exact combination of character traits you are describing. If you just mean sort of, kind of, in this general direction, then yes, you could say "respectful", "considerate", etc. But if you want that exact meaning, you have to spell it out.

I doubt that you'll get a closer fit than gracious:

gracious
a: marked by kindness and courtesy. a gracious host
b: characterized by charm, good taste, generosity of spirit, and
the tasteful leisure of wealth and good breeding.                                       [Merriam-Webster;
bolding
mine]

And generosity of spirit certainly involves the acknowledgement of the efforts of others:

To have generosity of spirit is to act with kindness, to be open and
willing to share with others without any expectation of receiving
something back in return. It means to celebrate the success and
efforts of others without envy or resentment.                                                                                         [Wellington
College]

A couple of examples:


Thank you once again for your gracious words recognizing the great and professional work of our entire team.                                   [Four Seasons Resort Marrakech]




A gracious person is slow to take credit and quick to lavish praise.                                                                                [Madison Christian
Church]



I think the word you're looking for is team player (At least in the sense most people use it). Other qualifiers could be

Easygoing
Agreeable
Accommodating
Inclusive
Open-minded


"yes-man" is a negative term meaning especially "one who endorses or supports without criticism every opinion or proposal of an associate or superior" (M-W). It doesn't refer to someone who gives credit to everyone, just someone who praises their boss or others in a higher position (generally for cynical reasons, to keep their job or get their boss to like them). The OP seems to want a positive, praiseworthy term for someone who sincerely acknowledges the contribution of everyone no matter how lowly.

I checked the dictionary meaning and was dismayed at the results, it's not the way it's used here in Nigeria at least to the best of my knowledge, it's synonymous with team player. So weird

Conscientious.
Cambridge Dictionary:

feeling a moral responsibility to do your work carefully and to be
fair to others:


She was a conscientious worker, and I’ll miss her.

See the sense of meaning captured in TechCrunch:

But it's important to be conscientious about off-color jokes in public
or in a workplace.


equitable (adj.)

Treating everyone fairly and in the same way
Cambridge


Having or exhibiting equity : dealing fairly and equally with all
concerned
M-W
Characterized by equity or fairness. Of actions, arrengements,
decisions, etc: That is in accordance with equity; fair, just,
reasonable.
[OED online]

Note that the OED also has:

Of persons: Guided by principles of equity, displaying a spirit of
equity; unbiased, impartial, candid. Now rare.

However,  Google Books does not appear to support this label.


Stuart, however, was not the equitable person that Edgar was.
Edgar's diary was kept without prejudice, and he gave credit where
it was due, even though he may not have liked the person deserving
such credit.
Gary Forney; Discovery Men (2009)


The equitable person will tend to choose and do what is
equitable and not be fussy about his own share.
Ronald Polansky; The Cambridge Companion to Aristotle's Nicomachean Ethics (2014)


I've never heard him say 'Ouch' even on a pack-horse trip over a
twelve-thousand-foot mountain range in Wyoming. He's an unbelievably
equitable guy on an outing.
Don Widener; Lemmon (1977)


Attentive seems to fit best in my opinion, or considerate if it's more about attitude/being respectful.
I'm not sure you could describe exactly that in a single word, however.
